# Can't save a list of numbers to models using api

Tags: python, django

im trying to create a list from 1 to 9 using the shell so the user can pick the number of tickets that he can book

shell:

```
>>> Passenger = list(range(1,10))
>>> Passenger.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Models.py:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    GENDER = (
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('f', 'Female'),
    )

    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, related_name="tickets", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booking_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_string], null=True, max_length=100, blank=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_string], null=True, max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_string], null=True, max_length=100, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True, null= True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.first_name)
```

Views.py:

```
def trips_page(request, trip_id):
    trip = get_object_or_404( Trip,pk=trip_id)
    error = None
    ticket = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        middle_name = request.POST.get('middle_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        ticket = Ticket(trip=trip,first_name=first_name, middle_name=middle_name,
            last_name=last_name, email=email,gender=gender)
        try:
            ticket.full_clean()
            ticket.save()
            return redirect('tickets',ticket_id=ticket.id)
        except ValidationError as e:
            error = dict(e)
            print(e)
    context = {'trip' : trip, 'error':error, 'ticket':ticket }
    return render(request, 'details/trips.html', context)
```

Comment: `Passenger = list(range(1,10))`: of course, these are not `Passenger` objects; it's just a list of the numbers 1 to 9. There's not Django can do with that.

Answer (score 0):

`list(range(1,10))` is just a list of numbers.

In order to be able to save a model object, you need to create one:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    Passenger.objects.create(pk=i)
```